# Laravel 5.4 - Adldap - Call to undefined method Adldap\Adldap::search()

Tags: laravel, adldap

I have an issue with my Laravel installation and the use of Adldap...
The error message I receive :

```
FatalThrowableError in UserCreationController.php line 100:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Adldap' not found
```

I have installed/deployed Adldap according to the documentation and it is working when I call it from some other location.

**Working stuff** :

```
Route::get('ldap', function() {
    $results = Adldap::search()->where('ou', 'ends_with', ' Users')
                               ->orWhere('ou','not_contains', 'Production')  
                               ->sortBy('ou', 'asc')
                               ->get();


    foreach ($results as $result) {
        dump ($result->ou);
    }
```

The page displays the dump correctly. All is fine.

**Not** working stuff (yields error code listed above).
Route calling a Controller...

Route :

```
Route::get('newuser', 'UserCreationController@GetUserOrganizationalUnits');
```

Controller :

```
public function GetUserOrganizationalUnits()
{
    $results = Adldap::search()->where('ou', 'ends_with', ' Users')
                               ->orWhere('ou','not_contains', 'Production')  
                               ->sortBy('ou', 'asc')
                               ->get();
    return view('newuserform',compact('results'));
}
```

Why is it working from the web php with the routes directly but not from the called Controller?

I already try adding explicitely the following as well...

```
use Adldap\Contracts\AdldapInterface;
```

The facade is declared and it works in the web routes without even calling this...

Can you please help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to include the Facade

Add: `use Adldap;` in your UserCreationController.php

Comment: Indeed, I did. Well. I didn't at first but I had other errors in the way which made me comment that out... and i thought i didn't need to do so as it was in the Facades and working from the web routes file...
**Thank you** - Issue solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to have this in your UserCreationController to get this working with the "use Adldap\Contracts\AdldapInterface;" approach:

```
protected $adldap;

public function __construct(AdldapInterface $adldap)
{
    $this->adldap = $adldap;
}
```

Or implement the facade in your config/app.php:

```
'Adldap' => Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap::class
```